# get only audio files from device storage with ionic 4 cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create audio player with Ionic framework (v. 4). It should use only local audio files stored on user phone. I need to get only audio files from device (FileEntry or full path).

Comment: Some code to show what you are trying to do might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need plugins as web APIs do support loading files from devices pretty broadly. Here is what you can do:

html: add Ionic button and place the file input inside of it.

```
<ion-button expand="full">
  <ion-icon lazy="true" slot="start" name="musical-notes"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label slot="end">Upload Sound</ion-label>
  <input type="file" (change)="loadSoundFileFromDevice($event)" id="file-input" accept="audio/mpeg, audio/wav">
</ion-button>
```

Note that you can restrict certain file types using mime types. See here for examples:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

ts: leverage fileReader API.

```
loadSoundFileFromDevice = (event) => {
  if (!event.target.files[0]) return;
  if (!file.type.match('audio')) return;
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  // do the blob:
  let blobReader = new FileReader();
  blobReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  blobReader.onload = () => {
    let blob: Blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array((blobReader.result as ArrayBuffer))]);
    let blobURL: string = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // do the rest with the actual file
  };
  // handle errors:
  blobReader.onerror = (error) => {
    this.foundation.handleError(error);
  };
};
```

I did not test this code but in theory once you obtained the file blob you should be able to leverage it in `<audio>` tag.

Comment: I think that this code will work as user should choose file. I don’t want in this way. I need to scan user phone and get all audio files in user phone.

Comment: fair but I am sure this is only achievable with Android, iOS will restrict access to very specific file folders on the users system